# How do I detect an infinite loop occuring in my code?

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

So my code is to check if a given number is a 'happy number'. It squares each digit of the number, adds them and continues to do so until either the result of the addition is 1 (which means it *is* a happy number) or until it results in a 4 (which means it is *not* a happy number).

What's happening is that there are many numbers which cause an infinite loop (therefore meaning they are not a happy number) and I'm wondering how I would construct my code so that it will detect when there's an infinite loop occuring? I have some ideas but all flawed.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;

namespace Happy_numbers_problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static int HappyNumbers(string Number)
        {
            string Output = Number;
            while ((Convert.ToInt32(Output) != 1) && (Convert.ToInt32(Output) != 4))
            {
                string Result2 = "0";
                
                for (int Index = 0; Index < Output.Length; Index++)
                {
                    string Character = Output.Substring(Index, 1);
                    int Calc = Convert.ToInt32(Character);
                    int Result = Calc * Calc;
                    //Adding Result2 and Result, then turning it into a string.
                    Result2 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Result2) + Result);
                    if (Index == (Output.Length) - 1)
                    {
                        Output = Result2;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(Output);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
            string Number = Console.ReadLine();
            int Output = HappyNumbers(Number);
            if (Output == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Number + " is a happy number");
            }
            else if (Output == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Number + " is not a happy number");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Number + " is not a happy number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in your while condition. If your output *needs* to be 1 or 4 to break out of the loop and deliver the output to latter be analysed, you have to use the operator *or* `||` instead of the operator *and* `&&`.

Comment: but this causes an infinite loop? The final value gets to 1 but when using | | it doesn't seem to stop the iteration. Unlike when && is used for some reason?

Comment: Use a debugger? It will be easier to pinpoint the infinite loop

Comment: Not necessary can cause a loop but has a chance because both of the conditions need to be matched to leave the loop, instead of one.